WordPress Customizer add_control Dropdown of Pages with Multi Select?
I have a customizer option that simply creates a dropdown populated with pages from the site. I need this dropdown to have the ability for multiple selections? Any ideas?
$wp_customize->add_control('options_my_dropdown',
    array(
       'label' => __('My Label'),
       'description' => esc_html__('My Description'),
       'section' => 'options_section',
       'type' => 'dropdown-pages'
    )
 );

